# How to create a Binding to an enum in Swift?

Tags: swift, binding, swiftui

I am failing to create a variable in the body of SwiftUI view as a Binding to an enum. I get the error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Binding<LifeEvent?>' with an
> argument list of type '(get: @escaping () -> LifeEvent?, set:
> @escaping () -> ())'

I get the same error if I change `LifeEvent?` for `LifeEvent`

```
enum LifeEvent: String, PickableEnum, Codable, Hashable { 
    case debutEtude
    case finEtude
    case dependence
    case deces
    case cessationActivite
    case liquidationPension
}

struct TimeSpanEditView: View {
  var body: some View {
     let internalToEvent = Binding<LifeEvent?> ( // I get the error here
            get: { () -> LifeEvent? in
                return LifeEvent.cessationActivite

            },
            set: {
            }
        )
```

Following this failing declaration I have other declarations as Bindings to Int that work perfectly:

```
let internalTo = Binding<Int> (
    get: {
        switch self.timeSpan {
            case .ending (let to, _),
                 .periodic(_ , _ , let to),
                 .spanning(_ , let to):
                return to
            default:
                return Date.now.year
        }
    },
    set: {
        switch self.timeSpan {
            case .ending (_, _):
                self.timeSpan = .ending(to: $0, toEvent: nil)
            case .periodic(let from, let period, _):
                self.timeSpan = .periodic(from: from, period: period, to: $0)
            case .spanning(let from, _):
                self.timeSpan = .spanning(from: from, to: $0)
            default:
                fatalError("ExpenseTimeSpan : Case out of bound")
        }
    }
)
```

**EDIT**

I cannot use `@State` as I need to take some actions and change values of my Model's properties when lifeEvent changes (=> goes in the set) and @State does not support WillSet whereas Bindings do support get/set.

Comment: What's the goal? Why just `@State var lifeEvent: LifeEvent?`, and @Binding to it where needed, does not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to `@Binding` you can use `@Published` in `@ObservableObject`:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var lifeEvent: LifeEvent? {
        didSet { // or alternatively willSet (depending on the use case)
            // do whatever you need just after the lifeEvent is changed
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TimeSpanEditView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    ...
}
```

And access your binding like this:

```
self.$viewModel.lifeEvent
```